# Android studio selecting wrong layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution, screen-density

I am new to Android. I am building my first application.

I have been trying to make it support multiple screens. I have gone through the developers section in android, but, I am not clear at these things.

1. What is the resolution, I should use for the different drawable folders?
   (for example an hdpi screen may have 500*600 screen or 1280*1920 screen.)
2. I have been using layout folders as mentioned in the developers page, like small, normal and the rest, but android keeps on selecting normal layouts for screens like nexus 6p(for which I am guessing large would be appropriate).

Is there any way I could make it look better??

Comment: you can provide a 1 higher resolution images, it will just fit on its container and scaled. just a reminder the orientation of the pic to be scaled properly. if its on landscape then provide a landscape images(width > height) and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
You have to write layout once but have to define dimensions dimens.xml for different different resolutions in app>res>values.

[image]

Comment: Here the dimens file for normal values folder contains resolution for below 5 inch screen, valuessw600dp contains resolution for 5 to 7 inch screen and values sw720dp contains resolution for above 7 inch screen

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am just curious, does it make the application work for all types of the screens like with different aspect ratios??  cause while using these folders for different layouts, I found that my UI's are misplacing even for a small change in the dimension.

Comment: Ya...you have to focus on one screen size. let suppos 7 inch, so that you have to change only in the sw600dp dimension file, no need to change in other dimensions..all are remains same.

Comment: My application is also working for the all types of screen...you have to maintain these three dimensions..if you are changing the dimensions value of sw720dp then you have to focus only for the 9 or 10 inches screen

Comment: Good logic . @Satya you should accept this answer .

Comment: Hey, saurabh, sorry it took so long, but I've been working on this..I have created different layout folders with different SW values. I have been using  sw400, sw600, sw720, sw780 folders in my application. Everything is working well, but, some screens in default folders are not looking good. For example I've been using galaxy S3(306ppi, SW-376), and HTC one(469ppi, SW-368) both using the default layout, but, they are not looking good. At the same time MOTO x(312 ppi, SW-369), Nexus 5(445ppi, SW-388) are working good. What might be the problem for this??

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate your layout or setting your content view you can try making method on your application if you have base activities or base fragments

```
//At base activity/fragment
protected boolean isLargeLayout() {
  return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.large_layout);
}
//Then at your real activity/fragment just call
if(isLargeLayout()) {
  //Set your layout knowing it's large
}else{
  //Normal layout
}
```

Or use straight something like

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.large_layout)) {
}
```

Or use dimens.xml with different dps (I do not prefer this method. I like android to choose which is large screen or not)