# ANDROID: ImageView for different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I am new to android studio; so please excuse if the query is trivial. My problem is with understanding the layouts.

My layout and the corresponding values folder is as shown below. My problem is that a correct layout is not being picked up. For example, for Nexus 4 (4.7inch, 768x1280, xhdpi), in the landscape mode, the layout is being picked up from the 'layout' folder. As per my understanding (which might be totally wrong :) ) it should have been picked from layout-sw720dp-xhdpi. Any suggestions please?

[layout-problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT4F4.png)

Comment: you can try my answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36785435/6097062

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANDROID Studio: Picking up seemingly wrong layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834204/android-studio-picking-up-seemingly-wrong-layout)

Comment: Saurabh thanks for the info, but your solution doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sw** stands for **smallest width**. So if the a device has a width of 320dp in portrait mode and 720dp in landscape mode then you end the device's smallest width is 320dp.

Try use layout-w720dp-xhdpi instead of layout-sw720dp-xhdpi and see if it works.

**How to calculate device dimensions in *dp***

1. [Calculate the PPI (Pixel per inch) of the device.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI)
   [image]
   [image]
2. [Calculate the dimensions of the device using dp](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html)
   [image]
   [image]
   Where:

   - [image] = Screen width in pixels
   - [image] = Screen height in pixels
   - [image] = Screen diagonal in pixels
   - [image] = Pixels per inch
   - [image] = Screen diagonal in inches

**Edit:**
 According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_%282013%29) "The Nexus 7 (2013) screen now has a 1920×1200 pixel resolution (960dp × 600dp)". So its smallest width is 600dp which is why your layout isn't being used.
**Proof**
PPI = (√(1920<sup>2</sup> + 1200<sup>2</sup>))/7.02 = 322.53
Width in dp = (1920*160)/322.53 = 952.47 = **Roughly 960dp**
Height in dp = (1920*160)/322.53 = 595.29 = **Roughly 600dp**

Comment: Thanks, will try. But pl could you let me know how did you determine 1920x1200 pixel = 960x600dp?. Understanding this will help! Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and why do we **x160** to calculate the dp? *"A dp is equal to one physical pixel on a screen with a density of 160"* according to the design guidelines.

Comment: Thats great. I think it will work, I was actually for some reason considering dp same as px

Comment: Patrick, it just occurred to me that for nexus 7, which has a sw of 600, the layout should be picked up from sw600dp, isnt it?

Comment: I will rephrase: For Nexus 4 (768 x 1280, 4.7inch screen), the calculations are: 386 x 644 dp. For landscape orientation, the smallest screen width is 644 dp, which is > 600dp; hence, as per my understanding, the layout should be picked up from sw600dp. I know I am wrong somewhere, but pl. could someone help? tnx.

Comment: That's because of the first thing I said in my answer. You're using **sw** rather than **w**. If I were to write it in Java psuedocode, `layout-sw600dp` will only be used if `600dp <= Math.min(386dp,644dp)`, which is simply not the case for your device, you probably want to use `layout-w600dp` which will be used if `600dp <= Current width of your screen in dp` <- So if you're in landscape mode, 600dp <= 644dp is true, therefore the layout will show.

Comment: In a nut shell, the Nexus 4 has a smallest width of 386dp, not 644dp

Comment: Many thanks @Patrick. I will try this tonight and update you. I am a bit more clearer on the minimum width concept. I was thinking that the min width is the one depending upon the orientation - so I was thinking that for portrait mode the min width is 386dp .. and for landscape mode it is 644dp

Comment: @hey, it worked. I had a wrong interpretation of sw. Thanks for the help! I could make my app live last night.

Comment: Good to hear that I helped you out. Congratulations on the app! :)